# ProgressIndicator finishes when I start another Stage

Tags: javafx, stage, progress-indicator

I want to create an application starter. The ProgressIndicator should running during start of the new Stage in new Thread. But if I click at the start button the ProgressIndicator stops running.

It works if I make some I/O and ProgressIndicator shows progress. It is apparently not possible to update two stages in JavaFX in parallel or does anyone have a solution for me?

```
   public class Main extends Application {
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new UserVC().getView(), 600, 200));
            primaryStage.show();
            userVC.autologin();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
    }

    public class UserView  extends BorderPane {
        private ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

        public UserView() {
            super.setCenter(createContent());
        }

        public Node createContent() {
            HBox userbox = new HBox();
            userbox.getChildren().add(progressIndicator);

            progressIndicator.show();

            return userbox;
        }
    }

    public class UserVC {
        private UserView view = new UserView();

        public UserVC() {
        }

        public void autologin() {
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                Stage stage = new Stage();
                                stage.setScene(new Scene(new MainControlVC().getView(), 900, 300));
                                stage.show();
                            }
                         });
                     }
                     catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     return null;
                }
            };

         view.getProgressIndicator().progressProperty().unbind();
         view.getProgressIndicator().progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());


            new Thread(task).start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps review this sample, which [Displays a JavaFX splash page for an intensive startup task with progress monitoring](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098).  Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Code does not compile.

Comment: Please create a [mre] that demonstrates the issue and COMPILES it will help others to understand what your issue is exactly

Comment: I created a minimal reproducible example because of your hints and behold, the progress indicator works and the problem no longer occurs. So it's not a javafx problem.

Comment: @jewelsea: nice demo. It looks good!

Comment: The initialisation of my embedded Derby Database stopped the Progress Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Task to Thread and it works fine now:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                mainController = new MainControlVC(dataDirectory, user);

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(mainController.getView(), mainController.getWidth(), mainController.getHeight());
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        thread.start();
```

Comment: glad you found a solution :) Though .. I guess (nothing more possible without you providing a [mcve] as already was suggested :) that your setup might be a bit upside-down - you really want to create and store something called MainXX from UserXX? Moreover, doing it from inside the threading code might be violating the fx-threading rule - blowing up (or not) sometime later.